# Description format for partial uploads of byte data using HTTP PATCH method

Tags: http, byte, patch, partial, json-patch

I want to use the HTTP PATCH method to add possibility of partial uploads to my REST interface. I found the [JSON Patch Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) and the [XML Patch Operation Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5261) which are used to update (and extend) existing JSON and XML resources via PATCH method partially. There are of course other ways to describe patch instruction, e.g. the [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-patch) format for patching JSON that don't comply with the [PATCH RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) - I'm look for those formats that do comply.

**TL;DR**:
How to describe patches for byte data? Is there any existing RFC or quasi-standard for describing those patches, especially data appending?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell: not yet. Somebody ought to write it down, defining a media type, and submit an Internet Draft.